# If $X$ is linearly independent, prove $X^{T}X$ is positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices

I understand this question has been asked before but I couldn't really find the answer I really need. I attempted this myself but I find that there is a contradiction in my answer.

Here is my attempt:

Let $Y=Xv$ and $Y>0$ where $X$ is a linearly independent matrix and $v$ is a vector.
Then $$Y^{T}Y = (Xv)^{T}(Xv) = v^{T}X^{T}Xv >0$$ Therefore, $X^{T}X$ is positive definite.

That being said, here is my second thought. If $X$ is linearly independent, that implies that $Y = 0$ ie $Xv = 0$ if and only if $v=0$. Therefore, $v^{T}X^{T}Xv=0$ but in order for it to be positive definite, $Y>0$ strictly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Let $Y = Vx$ and $Y > 0$". What do you mean by that? What is $x$ and $V$? Do you mean $Y = Xv$? What do you mean by $Y > 0$ and why are you allowed to assume this?

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch Sorry about the typing error, I fixed it and defined X and v. As far as Y>0 goes, I'm not even entirely sure I am allowed to assume this but I was told by a fellow classmate that Y>0 by definition but once again, I'll ask the experts on math stack exchange to guide me on whether or not I can use such an assumption

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wrote "If $X$ is linearly independent", but the assumption you actually need is that the **columns** of $X$ are linearly independent. That of course means there are at least as many rows as columns.

Suppose $X\in \mathbb R^{n\times k}.$ Then $X^T X \in \mathbb R^{k\times k}.$ Then for any $v\in\mathbb R^{k\times1}$ you have
$$
v^T\Big(X^T X\Big) v = (Xv)^T (Xv) = \|Xv\|^2 \ge 0.
$$
So $X^T X$ is nonnegative-definite.

The remaining problem is to show that if $v\ne0$ then $v^T\Big( X^T X\Big) v\ne0.$ It is clear that if $Xv\ne0$ then $(Xv)^T (Xv) \ne0.$ So the problem is to show that if $v\ne0$ then $Xv\ne0.$ Observe that $Xv$ is a linear combination of the columns of $X,$ and the coefficients in the linear combination are the entries in $v.$ So this says that $Xv=0$ only if $v=0,$ i.e. a linear combination of the columns of $X$ is $0$ only if the coefficients are $0.$ That is the definition of linear independence.

Comment: THANK YOU! Life savior.

Comment: @Michael Hardy:  I think you want $\Vert Xv \Vert^2 \ge 0$ in your one equation, no?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that the assertion, "X is linearly independent" means that *the columns of $X$ are linearly independent"; then if the columns of $X$ are denoted by $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$, so that

$X = \begin{bmatrix} X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n \end{bmatrix}, \tag 1$

then for any vector $v \ne 0$ we have

$y = Xv \ne 0; \tag 2$

this is easy to see; writing

$v = (v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n)^T, \tag 3$

we have

$y = Xv = \sum_1^n v_i X_i \ne 0 \tag 4$

for *any* $v$ by the linear independence of the $X_i$.  Then

$v^T(X^TX)v = (v^TX^T)(Xv)= (Xv)^T(Xv) = y^Ty > 0, \tag 5$

which says that $X^TX$ is positive definite.